# How to add a div with image and text 180 degree rotate in tcpdf

Tags: php, wordpress, tcpdf

I have searched a lot for this solution but no luck, as tcpdf have a poor documentation so i found nothing, what i need is a name plate print as pdf using tcpdf, ant the template is so simple just as the image is [image: http://prntscr.com/ezrdsp]

But the problem is i can not rotate the top section properly. here is my code

```
    $obj_pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $obj_pdf->AddPage('L' , 'A5');
    $obj_pdf->StartTransform();
    $obj_pdf->Rotate(-180);

    $obj_pdf->image($logo1, 165 , 65, 0, 90, "PNG", "" , "M", true);
    $obj_pdf->image($logo2, 0 , 65, 0, 90, "PNG", "" , "R", true);

    $name =  $functional_user->first_name .' '. $functional_user->last_name ;
    $obj_pdf->SetTopMargin(-120);
    $obj_pdf->SetLeftMargin(10);
    $obj_pdf->setCellPaddings(0,0,0,0);
    $tbl = '<br> <div class= "rotate" style="transform: rotate(180deg);">
            <table cellpadding="2" >
            <tr>
                <td><h1 style = "font-size: 40px; line-height: 1.3">'.$name.' </h1>
                <br><br><span style="font-size: 13px">
                '.$org_logo_text.' </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>';
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
    $obj_pdf->StopTransform();

    $obj_pdf->SetTopMargin(78);
    $obj_pdf->image($logo1, 10 , 70, 40, 20, "PNG", "" , "M", true);
    $obj_pdf->image($logo2, 165 , 70, 40, 20, "PNG", "" , "R", true);

    $name =  $functional_user->first_name .' '. $functional_user->last_name ;
    $obj_pdf->SetTopMargin(100);
    $obj_pdf->SetLeftMargin(10);
    $obj_pdf->setCellPaddings(0,0,0,0); 
    $tbl = '<br>
            <table cellpadding="2" >
            <tr>
                <td><h1 style = "font-size: 40px; line-height: 1.3">'.$name.' </h1>
                <br><br><span style="font-size: 13px">
                '.$org_logo_text.' </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>';
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
    $obj_pdf->lastPage();
    $obj_pdf->Output('/tmp/Nameplate_' . $i . '.pdf', 'F');
    $obj_pdf->Close();
```

Can somebody help me with this ??

Comment: What results you got?

Comment: What i got the text and image change their position but not rotate properly, please check this image

http://prntscr.com/ezs9yj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved this my own, what i did wrong is using rotate($angle) function. And it does actually rotate the section but it take the center point as (0,0) or left-top corner And so that after rotate the whole section places outside of the pdf page. So finally i use rotate($angle, $px, $py) function where px and py will push that section from corresponding axis and places the required place . Here is my code

```
    $obj_pdf->StartTransform();
    $angle= 180;
    $px= 105;
    $py= 36;
    $obj_pdf->Rotate($angle, $px, $py);

    $obj_pdf->image($company_logo, 10 , 0, 40, 20, "PNG", "" , "M", true);
    $obj_pdf->image($organization_logo, 165 , 0, 40, 20, "PNG", "" , "R", true);

    $name =  $functional_user->first_name .' '. $functional_user->last_name ;
    $obj_pdf->SetTopMargin(27);
    $obj_pdf->SetLeftMargin(10);
    $fz = "35px";
    if( strlen( $name )> 20) $fz = "40px";
    else if( strlen($name)> 18 ) $fz = "33px";
    $tbl = '<br><table cellpadding="1" >
            <tr>
                <td><h1 style = "font-size: '.$fz.'; line-height: 1.3">'.$name.' </h1>
                <br><br><span style="font-size: 13px">
                '.$org_logo_text.' </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>';
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
    $obj_pdf->StopTransform();
```